Is the acquisition of knowledge an intrinsic good?
I'm not a philosopher, but I've read questions on whether knowledge is an intrinsic good. However, I have not been able to find anything on the acquisition of knowledge. Is the acquisition of knowledge an intrinsic good and if so why? How can we actually test if something is intrinsically good. The test of isolation doesn't seem to work in this case.
Additionally, I know that knowledge is supposed to be a belief that is both justified and true, and if so, does that mean that knowledge is always the truth? And secondly, is truth intrinsically good?

Knowledge is usually a partial truth. A little learning may be a dangerous thing. And fools rush in, where angels fear to tread. See Alexander Pope's An Essay on Criticism.

According to many philosophers, yes, see Greco, The value of knowledge:"Many philosophers have thought that knowledge has a different kind of value, over and above the practical value that it has. For example, knowledge seems to be valuable for itself, as opposed to being valuable merely as a means for getting something else. In related fashion, knowledge seems to be valuable in itself, as opposed to being valuable merely insofar as it is related to other things." Some do dispute it and argue that the value of knowledge is illusory.

Many philosophers say knowledge is inherently good, but does that imply the acquisition of knowledge is also inherently good?

Not if it is used for evil purposes, for example knowledge of how to make a bomb, or to disrupt an election process, etc.

Ecclesiastes disagrees: in much wisdom is much grief, and he that increases knowledge increases sorrow.

The view that "knowledge is justified true belief" is not generally accepted and there are strong reasons not to accept it. It's also pretty easy to think of cases in which it's better not to know something, so in that sense knowledge is not generally just good in itself.

It's definitely not wise to ignore or dismiss age-old practical wisdom and experience, as expressed in for instance Ecclesiastes or other wisdom literature (it's possible to appreciate that without buying into the religious context).

Typically, knowledge acquisition is an instrumental good: a means to an end. Having knowledge alone might be intrinsically good but it also might be useless information without any application.

I would say it depends; that is, acquiring some knowledge is intrinsically good in some ways.  It covers such a broad category that it might be like asking whether insects are intrinsically good or bad for your garden.
For instance, here are a couple of counter-examples.  First, it can bring great grief and sadness to acquire knowledge about the details of the evil in this world (as mentioned in the comments, attested by the wisest man to live, King Solomon).  That doesn't mean it's necessarily wrong, though; sometimes, we need to know about evil for our own protection, or to help others; and sometimes, people simply can't help learning about it because of their environment.  Many law enforcement officials learn a lot more than they would care to know about evil, and it weighs them down; but they do it in order to protect the rest of us.  And so it can be used for good, but it's not exactly beneficial to the person learning it.  When there isn't a good reason, it's best to avoid more of that kind of knowledge, for our own well-being.
Second, too much acquisition can be exhausting!  (Again, as King Solomon also said, Ecclesiastes 12:12; an insightful guy!)  That doesn't make it wrong, and some people seem to have a marathon-like stamina when it comes reading all sorts of books and remembering the content, which I don't; but we are all finite and have our limit at some point.  And we should be okay with that.  :)
So to summarize, as with many things, I would say that I guess it depends.

+1 A related topic is curiosity. Curiosity is an intrinsic trait but it is not necessarily an intrinsic good: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/curiosity-is-not-intrinsically-good/
